# How to make dynamically added methods visible to Rails 4.2.0 controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

Here is the way dynamic methods are added to application controller in Rails 3.2.12:

```
 module WfHelper
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
       before_action :load_wf_action_def
    end

    protected
    def load_wf_action_def
      #load methods with eval()
    end
  end
```

In application controller, the module wf_helper is included:

```
 include WfHelper
```

All methods defined in `load_wf_action_def`are available to application controller. After upgrading to Rails 4.2.0 however, the code stops working and the methods are no longer visible by application controller. Debug shows `base.before_action :load_wf_action_def` is executed normally but its methods were not added to `action_methods` of the controller class(`AbstractController::ActionNotFound` when calling a dynamic method). The problem is from base.rb in action pack. We don't know what exactly the change in base.rb causes the code broken. Is there someone who added dynamic method to controller for Rails 4 and would like to share the experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to add the actions manually to `Controller.action_methods` and it solves the problem.

Comment: Can you include the code you used and where you put it in order to get the router to see the added action?